# i am unsure how the grid system works in the layout that i bought

Tags: html, css, responsive

i bought a responsive html5 layout and i installed it in www.cdauae.com/new

i am familiar with how the grid system works. for example in another website of mine that uses a different layout i said something like:-

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="eight columns">xyz</div>
   <div class="eight columns">xyz</div>
</div>
```

here there are sixteen columns in a row and i divided row into 2 parts and each part is 8 columns

however in the new layout it says things like col-md, col-lg and col-sm. i am unsure how to use them. i know that the new layout has 12 columns in a row

for example on the homepage they wanted to divide row into 3 parts and each part is 4 columns. they wrote:-

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-4">xyz</div>
</div>
```

i dont understand that. why did they combine both col-md and col-lg in the same line of code? there are also parts in which they combined col-md, col-lg and col-sm in the same line of code

i will get the same result if i say:-

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">xyz</div>
</div>
```

and if i say:-

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">xyz</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">xyz</div>
</div>
```

that confused me. when do i combine? when do i use col-md by itself? when do i use col-lg by itself? when do i use col-sm by itself?

Comment: Congratulation, you just brought *FREE* Bootstrap template. Go to bootstrap webpage and see how it works. `-xs-`, `-sm-`, `-md-` and `-lg-` indicates browser width, number indicates columns count.

Comment: Check [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/).

Answer (score 1):

Adding `col-lg-* , col-md-*, col-sm-*` classes defines on the same line says which class will get applied based on screen resolution.

`col-lg-*` classes  gets applied after a min-width: 992px of that framework.

`col-md-*` classes  gets applied after a min-width: 768px of that framework.

Check the below image for example:

[image]

watch this video for the explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xinn-BtAGpk

Comment: Aptly said, and your col-md-* col-lg-* will be applied based on the width has been mentioned in the answer, so they have to be on same line to define the different behavior in different screen size.

Comment: @PM. yes, keeping classes on the same line will gets applied based on screen size.

Comment: so how do i use it? what will happen if i say only col-lg and i open it on a medium device? will it spoil? or will it fix itself according to default behavior and i say col-lg and col-md together if i want to override the default behavoir?

Comment: @shiddo, this will not break your layout if you are using `col-lg-12` on a smaller device. For example check your 'Who We Are:' section is using full width on the large screen, this will also use full screen in mobile too.

Comment: good. i want my website to work well on all screen sizes, but it will be quite confusing if have to combine all col-lg, col-md, col-sm and i give each device a different number of columns. is it ok if i say something like col-lg-6 col-md-6 and col-lg-6 col-md-6 so i can divide the row into 2 parts that have 6 columns each? on a smaller screen 2 parts in a row wont fit so it should automatically convert to 2 rows

Comment: framework does that for you, else you can even explicitly say to use single row in smaller devices like `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12` .

Comment: so if i only say col-md-6 and if it is opened on a large screen it will automatically become col-md-6 col-lg-6?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered above so I'm just added this for reference:

This is the standard bootstrap responsive design system:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/grid/